# Log and messages panel "gone"?

Tags: texniccenter

I don't know if I accidentally did something, but now I can't see the log-and-messages-panel where I normally see if there were any overfull boxes or errors etc after compiling... How can I make this box visible again? Thanks.

Ps. Menu-stuff are now for me File/Edit/Search/View/Insert/Math/Format/Project/build/Tools/Window/Help... I don't think I had all of these earlier today. What happened? :(

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Which editor are you using?

Comment: I found that changing the monitor screen resolution caused the build window to reappear.

Answer (score 6):

In [TeXnicCenter](http://www.texniccenter.org/), you probably pressed Escape while the "Output" window was active. This unpins it from the interface, effectively removing it from view.

To restore this window in V 1.00 (Stable), follow View > Output Bar:

[image]

To restore this window in V 2.02+, follow View > Tool Windows > Build Output (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>).

[image]

Comment: How do I move the build output window back on screen, when it is off-screen (due to a different previous monitor set-up)?

Comment: @FrankSeifert: Change the monitor settings to "Duplicate", which should place everything on a single screen. Then fix your settings/display/layout. Then revert back to "Extend display".

Comment: Unfortunately, the build output window remains off screen and out of reach today, even with the "Duplicate screens" setting. Any other idea?

Comment: You can manually move the monitor positions around in the "Extended screens" setting until the output window is found (worked today) but that is not an ideal solution.